# How to remove array keys 1 level in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to remove 1 level of the nesting array keys.Because it causes for looping.if i loop this this will take 2 for loops but i need only one foreach loop that's enough.so that I had tried some PHP array functions but not related to this.So that i need the answer or suggestions.

Now my array values showing like this.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [post_id] => 1332
                [meta_value] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"302";}
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [post_id] => 1337
                [meta_value] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"296";}
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [post_id] => 1337
                [meta_value] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"302";}
            )

    )

)
```

Now i want looking like this.

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
         (
              [post_id] => 1332
              [meta_value] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"302";}
         )

  [1] => Array
         (
              [post_id] => 1337
              [meta_value] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"296";}
         )

  [2] => Array
         (
             [post_id] => 1337
                [meta_value] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"302";}
         )
   )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well you will need to still append those values to some other array. At first there are 2 different arrays that will have to be merged. So the structure changes. You probably will not be able to escape additional for-loops and foreach clauses.

Comment: first guess - using `array_pop($val)` in first `foreach ($arr as $key => $val) `should work.

Comment: if there are no additional dimensions then `$whatYouWant = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $yourArray);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function array_unchank($array) {
    if (empty($array)) {
        return array();
    }
    return call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
}
```

Use: `print_r(array_unchank($array) );`

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code Hope this helps you

```
$input = array(
array
(
    array
        (
            'post_id' => 1332,
            'meta_value' => 'a:1:{i:0;s:3:"302";}'
        )

),
array
(
    array
        (
            'post_id'  => 1337,
            'meta_value'=> 'a:1:{i:0;s:3:"296";}'
        ),
        array
        (
            'post_id' => 1337,
            'meta_value'=> 'a:1:{i:0;s:3:"302";}'
        )

)
);

$result = call_user_func_array("array_merge", $input);

var_export($result);
```